# stormpath can't create groups for google sign in directory

Tags: python, google-identity-toolkit, stormpath

Installed stormpath and using google sign in to register and sign in. 
Now I'm trying to create groups in the google directory in stormpath using this

```
from stormpath.client import Client
stormpath_client = Client(id=STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID, secret=STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET)
directory = stormpath_client.applications[0].account_store_mappings[1].account_store
directory.groups.create({'name': 'admins'})
```

based on [this toturial](http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.org/en/latest/product.html#enforce-user-authorization)

I get and error

```
Cannot create nor edit accounts of externally managed directories.
```

I get the same error if I try to create groups in the stormpath console.

[image]

How do I give different users different permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a gist for sample code for this `stormpath`workaround in `python  Flask`

environment.py
https://gist.github.com/ohadperry/f77a26ce758efa2990cb

authentication_controller.py
https://gist.github.com/ohadperry/338e7e689d8c64158c06

stormpath_helper.py
https://gist.github.com/ohadperry/50951e68f2375f0b9002

The basic logic is :

1. log in with the google user.
2. find or create a use in the cloud directory
3. switch to the new cloud user using flask login

   ```
   from flask.ext.stormpath import User as StormpathUser
   from flask.ext.login import login_user 
   new_user_account.__class__ = StormpathUser
   # switching the session
   login_user(new_user_account, remember=True)
   ```

Comment: @jfive yes, it did and used in production

Answer (score 2):

Stormpath doesn't allow you to create Groups for social Directories (like your Google Directory, here).

What you have to do is create a normal Stormpath Directory (not a social one), create your user there, and then you can do stuff like create Groups, etc.

What I like to do (personally), is this:

- Once a user signs in via Google, I'll create a copy of that user account in my main Stormpath Directory.
- Then I'll use the copy of that user in the Stormpath Directory as that user's 'main' account, and create Groups / etc. there.

Comment: hi, this is an extremely ugly hack. after duplicating the user. how would he login to the system? using google? when I do this my user object is the original one , not the duplicate one.

Comment: also, after adding `@groups_required(['admins'])` to route I'm getting an error `"ValueError('Invalid Group name specified.',)"` even though `admins` are created in the main cloud directory

Comment: @WebQube we're currently adding support for this sort of workflow into our core API, we call it 'unified social identity'. The idea is that we'll have a SINGLE user record that *all* of your user accounts are linked to. So if a user signs up via email/password on your site, then creates a Facebook account, they'll have 2 user accounts, but they'll both be linked to the 'main' account record for that user. That's what I'm describing above. It's a good interim solution until we have this in our core API =)

Comment: What I'm saying that I can't even get the hack to work.  when the user logs in with google , he get's the original google account not the duplicated account, obviously. since the callback he is directed is myapp.com/google -> from there to [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/blob/master/flask_stormpath/views.py#L349)  and then `user.directory` is the google directory and no groups are avialabe

Comment: Oh, I see. That's correct -- what you need to do is: after the user logs in with Google login, you get back a Google account. Then you need to execute a search query against your MAIN stormpath directory for that same user account by email, retrieve the OTHER account, then UPDATE your session tokens to use the NEW account for all future requests. I've built a sample app which shows how to do this using Node.js: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express-social-unification-example I'll try to build a Python sample when I get the chance.

Comment: hi @rdegges , got the main cloud user by email but I can't seem to switch user in the session  ,tried `login_user(new_user_account, remember=True)` but it fails due to 'Account has no attribute is_active'. does `Flask-storpath` has a built in method to switch?

Comment: @rdegges A little late to the show here, but currently experiencing the exact same issue, just wondered whether there was any update on integration into Stormpath Core API? Or a Python example?

Answer (score 0):

The problem can now also be solved from within the Stormpath admin panel. The underlying procedure is very similar to the one described in the other two answers but can now be achieved with just a few clicks in the Stormpath website.

**PROCEDURE**

1. [Log in](https://api.stormpath.com/login) to your Stormpath account.
2. Click on `Applications` in the top nav bar.
3. Click on you application and then select `Policies` in the left hand
   menu.
4. Under `Account Linking Policy`, set the `Status` to `Enabled` and
   `Automatic Provisioning` to `Enabled`.
5. THAT'S IT!

Once this is complete, when a user signs in with Social Login for the first time, Stormpath will create another account under the application's default directory that is linked to the social login account. You can now create groups and assign the user account in the default directory to the group, which will by extension, also add the social login to the group. This works because the two accounts (the social login and the other one created in the default directory) are linked to each other.

See [here](https://stormpath.com/blog/unify-social-accounts-account-linking#using-account-linking) for more details.